# How can i get http based heroku domain

Tags: heroku

I created a new heroku nodejs app.

And i received the domain name with `HTTPS`.

I am using an API where service provider provides only `http` based requests.

Now the question is can i run heroku app on http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Heroku app will respond to both ports 80 (http) and 443 (https) on the herokuapp.com domain you were given. So if your app is called `myapp`, you can access it via http://myapp.herokuapp.com and https://myapp.herokuapp.com